# Elixir compile-time code injection / AOP

Tags: erlang, aop, elixir

I've previously used AOP-style code to separate Logic from Logging, and been very pleased with the results.  I recognize that opinions on AOP vary, but I'd like to figure out a solution in Elixir, even if I don't end up using it in prod.

The closest example I've seen is the setup callback inside of ExUnit, which allows execution of code before each test runs;  I'd like to do something similar, but haven't been able to muddle through the ExUnit source to grasp the intuitions there.

In code form:

```
defmodule Project.Logic do
    LoggingInjection.inject Project.Logging

    def work_do_stuff(arg) do
        #...
        #returns some_result
    end
end
```

in a separate code file:

```
defmodule Project.Logging do
    #called just before Project.Logic.work_do_stuff with the same args
    def before_work_do_stuff(arg) do
        Log.write("about to work_do_stuff with #{inspect arg}")
    end
    # def after_work_do_stuff(some_result) implicitly defined as no-op,
    # but could be overridden.
end
```

and finally, the real question:  What is the code to enable this magic?

```
defmodule LoggingInjection do
    defmacro inject(logging_module) do
        #What goes here?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not AOP, but if you're interested in observing function calls at runtime, you can consider looking into Erlang trace.

For example, you can use `:dbg` to setup dynamic traces of function calls. Here's how to trace all calls to `IO`:

```
iex> :dbg.tracer
iex> :dbg.p(:all, [:call])
iex> :dbg.tp(IO, [{:_, [], [{:return_trace}]}])

(<0.53.0>) call 'Elixir.IO':puts(stdio,<<"\e[33m{:ok, [{:matched, :nonode@nohost, 28}, {:saved, 1}]}\e[0m">>)
(<0.53.0>) returned from 'Elixir.IO':puts/2 -> ok
(<0.59.0>) call 'Elixir.IO':gets(stdio,<<"iex(4)> ">>)
```

I occasionally use this feature to connect to a running BEAM node, and analyze the running system. Be sure to stop traces with `:dbg.stop_clear` once you're done.

If you want to manually handle trace messages and do something specific about them (e.g. log them to a file), you can use `:erlang.trace`. Here's a simple `gen_server` that traces calls to various modules:

```
defmodule Tracer do
  use GenServer

  def start(modules), do: GenServer.start(__MODULE__, modules)

  def init(modules) do
    :erlang.trace(:all, true, [:call])

    for module <- modules do
      :erlang.trace_pattern({module, :_, :_}, [{:_, [], [{:return_trace}]}])
    end

    {:ok, nil}
  end

  def handle_info({:trace, _, :call, {mod, fun, args}}, state) do
    IO.puts "called #{mod}.#{fun}(#{Enum.join(Enum.map(args, &inspect/1), ",")})"
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def handle_info({:trace, _, :return_from, {mod, fun, arity}, res}, state) do
    IO.puts "#{mod}.#{fun}/#{arity} returned #{res}"
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def handle_info(_, state), do: {:noreply, state}
end
```

To use it, just start it and provide the list of modules you want to trace:

```
iex(2)> Tracer.start([IO])
{:ok, #PID<0.84.0>}

called Elixir.IO.puts(:stdio,"\e[33m{:ok, #PID<0.84.0>}\e[0m")
Elixir.IO.puts/2 returned ok
call Elixir.IO.gets(:stdio,"iex(3)> ")
```

Tracing is very powerful and you can do all sorts of thing with it. I didn't use it for a logging system myself, so I can't say how much of a problem it will be, so if you take this road, I advise you to be careful and observe performance, because too much of tracing might overload your system.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to propose a complete different approach to the problem: [GenEvent](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/GenEvent.html).

The ExUnit way works for ExUnit because it is a test framework and it can impose restrictions on how the test runs and therefore how your code should be written. For your actual application, that includes Logging and other things, an event based system seems to be much more robust solution which can easily benefit from concurrency too.

The idea is that you will start a GenEvent and send events to it. Your Logger will be a handler installed in the GenEvent. You can choose for the published events to be either sync or async. The example in our documentation covers exactly this case.

Comment: Concurrency is an excellent addition to this scheme, and I'd be happy to embrace a GenEvent approach;  what I would need in order to make it satisfy the primary requirement **(separation of logging from logic)** is a way to dispatch an event at the beginning and end of each method call; to have those events include argument/return/method information; and to hide all the boilerplate at the beginning/end of each function.  code that substitutes `GenEvent.notify` for `Logging.log` doesn't solve the primary requirement.

Comment: Well, your code does not know anything about Logging. GenEvent is meant to provide a generic extension point that can be used for anyone and is not coupled to the implementation.

In any case, to directly answer your question, there is no way to do the separation at compile time as you want today (no library or example that I know off). :)

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on this question with the same need. Not my solution, putting it here for anyone reference, I found an excellent [tutorial series](http://www.theerlangelist.com/article/macros_1) on macros and how to extract function def info by [Saša Jurić](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2122760/sasajuric) and [a way to override the 'def' macro](https://gist.github.com/sasa1977/a14f8dd76fe437668ac1) also by him.

Basically:

1. In order to decorate function declaration, you can exclude the default import of the 'def' macro from the Kernel module.

   ```
   import Kernel, except: [def: 2]
   ```
2. Provide a custom implementation of the 'def' macro which will extract the function declaration info for the AST node - name and arguments - and generate a code that do the actual 'Kernel.def', inside it do the logging for example and do the original code  for the function.

   ```
   defmacro def(fn_call_ast, fn_opts_ast) do    
     result_fn_call_ast = process_call_ast fn_call_ast
     result_fn_opts_ast = process_opts_ast fn_opts_ast

     quote do
       Kernel.def(
         unquote(result_fn_call_ast), unquote(result_fn_opts_ast))
     end
   end
   ```

I have put those two solutions together and created a [package](https://github.com/elpddev/elixir-function-decorating) implementing those. Intended only for experimenting. So you can do:

```
defmodule User do
  use FunctionDecorating
  decorate_fn_with LogDecorator

  def say(word) do
    word
  end
end

iex>User.say("hello")
#PID<0.86.0> [x] Elixir.User.say(["hello"]) -> "hello"
"hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind decorating your functions with attributes, you can use: https://github.com/arjan/decorator

It is pretty unobtrusive.  You can make a LogDecorator like this:

```
defmodule LogDecorator do
  use Decorator.Define, [log: 0]
  require Logger

  def log(body, context) do
    quote do
      self = unquote(__MODULE__)
      data =
        unquote(Macro.escape(context))
        |> Map.delete(:__struct__)
        |> Map.merge(%{
            args: self.listify(unquote(context.args)),
            returned: unquote(body)
          })

      self.trace_function(data)
      data.returned
    end
  end

  def listify(arg) when is_list(arg), do: arg
  def listify(arg) when is_map(arg), do: Enum.into(arg, [])
  def listify(arg), do: [arg]

  def trace_function(ctx) do
    Logger.info("Function Invocation #{inspect ctx}")
  end
end
```

To use it you would place attributes on functions you want to trace like this:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  use LogDecorator

  @decorate log()
  def square(a) do
    a * a
  end

  @decorate log()
  def add(a, b) do
    a + b
  end
end
```