# Can function application be overriden with Macro in Elixir?

Tags: metaprogramming, elixir

Let's say I'd want to override each function call with a macro that counts how many times I called each particular function.
 Is it possible in Elixir?

I know there is a possibility of overriding builtin macros and functions with

```
import Kernel, except: [name: arity]
import MyOwnKernel
```

But it doesn't seem to work for apply/2 nor apply/3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. Those are defined as special forms (`Kernel.SpecialForms`) and they cannot be overridden.

Comment: Can def/2 be overriden? If yes how to call original def inside it if there are no function aliases

Comment: @KrzysztofWende You can implement your own def macro. IIRC Dave Thomas has explained this technique in "Programming Elixir". I made a quick gist at https://gist.github.com/sasa1977/a14f8dd76fe437668ac1  Probably missing some nuances, but hopefully illustrates the idea. Note though that I'd be very careful about using this approach in prod (in fact most probably I wouldn't use it)

Comment: No prob, but be really careful about how you use it. Having custom def in prod code can really obfuscate code. However if you plan on using it just for some dev-time experiments, then it's probably fine.

Answer (score 4):

Not the answer to your direct question, but if you really want to trace function calls and do some analysis, you may consider Erlang tracing capabilities. I provided a simple example [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907523/elixir-compile-time-code-injection-aop/28914950#28914950).

Also, you might look into [fprof](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/fprof.html) for profiling, which can give you function count. IIRC `fprof` analyzes only the process in which you start it, and you can't run multiple profiles simultaneously.

Comment: I'd guess that wanting to count the number of times a function has been called is related to profiling so I'd guess fprof is probably what he's looking for.

Comment: That is a cool thing to know. But unfortunatelly that was just an exemplary case to simplify the thing I want to achieve.

BTW is that tracing based on Prolog's tracing? It looks similar

Comment: @sasajuric plus the biggest disadvantage is it works at runtime instead of compile-time

Comment: @KrzysztofWende yeah, I suspected that was not your actual case. Perhaps it's best to visit elixir-lang-talk mailing list and explain your specific problem.